# How to read computer's datetime format and change the code appropriately

Tags: c#, .net

I have some code that subtracts user specified number of days from a todays date and writes something out. We used dd-mm-yyyy format. During testing, on machines that have mm-dd-yyyy format it subtacted months instead of days.
Looks like this:

```
DateTime Date1 = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(days, 0, 0, 0));
```

How can we read the computer's datetime format, and modify the subtract if the format is different than ours.

Thanks.

Comment: It didn't subtract months, it subtracted the number of `days` your testing has been confused by the date formatting on the machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you not just do :

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

This code shows how to get the running machine's formatting, and hopefully shows that you shouldn't need to worry about it when manipulating dates, just when you output it.

and... http://xkcd.com/1179/

```
int days = 1;

DateTime n = DateTime.Now;

Console.WriteLine( "Now using a fixed known format for tests");
Console.WriteLine( "{0:yyyy MM dd}" , n);
Console.WriteLine();

DateTime Date1 = n.Subtract(new TimeSpan(days, 0, 0, 0));

Date1.Dump();


DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat;

Console.WriteLine("machines short date pattern");
Console.WriteLine( dtfi.ShortDatePattern );
Console.WriteLine("{0:d}" , Date1);
Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine("machines long date pattern");
Console.WriteLine( dtfi.LongDatePattern );
Console.WriteLine("{0:D}" , Date1);
```

Outputs on my machine:

```
Now using a fixed known format for tests
2013 08 07


06/08/2013 10:05:06
machines short date pattern
M/d/yyyy
06/08/2013

machines long date pattern
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy
06 August 2013
```